# Google Map embedded into webpage overflows its boundaries when printed to wkhtmltopdf

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to track down a weird bug, where an embedded Google map looks just fine in the HTML version of the page, but when we PDF-ify it using wkhtmltopdf, the map, while staying within its box, also continues into the adjacent page.  In other words, if the map's at the bottom of a page, the next page has more map (whatever would be in the next part of the map had the map been bigger) overlapping the content at the top.  If the map's at the top of a page, the previous page gets the extra map content.
[The same page in three formats. Please forgive the rough MS Paint anonymization.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPnxG.jpg)

I've tried many things, including:

- Adding extra divs all over the place (before, after, immediately
  before, immediately after, etc.)
- Trying different overflow values for both the div the map's in, and its containing divs
- Commenting out the overlays on the map
- Tried and failed to use my Google-fu to find a solution
- And probably several other things which I can't remember at the moment.

Has anyone seen anything like this?  Any thoughts as to what might be causing it, or suggestions for directions I should explore?

Fiddle of just the relevant section at https://jsfiddle.net/cosmos42/wj81zc13/1/ - hopefully it has all the necessary information.  I took our URLs and other identifying information out of the fiddle, so the Google map won't actually work...

Thanks in advance for your help.

```js
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(38.8977, -77.0366);

function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.8977, -77.0366),
    zoom: 19,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false,
    rotateControl: false
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
  });

  marker.setMap(map);


  var ParcelLayer = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
      var proj = map.getProjection();
      var zfactor = Math.pow(2, zoom);
      // get Long Lat coordinates
      var top = proj.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(coord.x * 256 / zfactor, coord.y * 256 / zfactor));
      var bot = proj.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point((coord.x + 1) * 256 / zfactor, (coord.y + 1) * 256 / zfactor));

      //corrections for the slight shift of the SLP (mapserver)
      var deltaX = 0.00;
      var deltaY = 0.00;

      //create the Bounding box string
      var bbox = (top.lng() + deltaX) + "," +
        (bot.lat() + deltaY) + "," +
        (bot.lng() + deltaX) + "," +
        (top.lat() + deltaY);

      //base WMS URL
      var url = "http://gis.someotherwebsitethatisntours.net:9080/geoserver/ttb/wms?";
      url += "&REQUEST=GetMap"; //WMS operation
      url += "&SERVICE=WMS"; //WMS service
      url += "&VERSION=1.1.0"; //WMS version  
      //url += "&LAYERS=" + "fm:parcel_socal"; //WMS layers
      url += "&LAYERS=" + "ttb:parcels_ca"; //WMS layers
      url += "&FORMAT=image/png"; //WMS format
      url += "&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF";
      url += "&TRANSPARENT=TRUE";
      url += "&SRS=EPSG:4326"; //set WGS84 
      url += "&BBOX=" + bbox; // set bounding box
      url += "&WIDTH=256"; //tile size in google
      url += "&HEIGHT=256";
      return url; // return URL for the tile

    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true,
  });

  var FloodLayer = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
      var proj = map.getProjection();
      var zfactor = Math.pow(2, zoom);
      // get Long Lat coordinates
      var top = proj.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(coord.x * 256 / zfactor, coord.y * 256 / zfactor));
      var bot = proj.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point((coord.x + 1) * 256 / zfactor, (coord.y + 1) * 256 / zfactor));

      //corrections for the slight shift of the SLP (mapserver)
      var deltaX = 0.00;
      var deltaY = 0.00;

      //create the Bounding box string
      var bbox = (top.lng() + deltaX) + "," +
        (bot.lat() + deltaY) + "," +
        (bot.lng() + deltaX) + "," +
        (top.lat() + deltaY);

      //base WMS URL
      var url = "http://gis.someotherwebsitethatisntours.net:9080/geoserver/ttb/wms?";
      url += "&REQUEST=GetMap"; //WMS operation
      url += "&SERVICE=WMS"; //WMS service
      url += "&VERSION=1.1.0"; //WMS version  
      //url += "&LAYERS=" + "fm:parcel_socal"; //WMS layers
      url += "&LAYERS=" + "ttb:flood_poly"; //WMS layers
      url += "&FORMAT=image/png"; //WMS format
      url += "&BGCOLOR=0x99FF00";
      url += "&TRANSPARENT=TRUE";
      url += "&SRS=EPSG:4326"; //set WGS84 
      url += "&BBOX=" + bbox; // set bounding box
      url += "&WIDTH=256"; //tile size in google
      url += "&HEIGHT=256";
      return url; // return URL for the tile

    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true,
  });

  map.overlayMapTypes.push(ParcelLayer);


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, \'load\', initialize);
```

```css
   * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   .clear {
     clear: both;
     display: block;
     height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     visibility: hidden;
     width: 0;
   }
   body {
     overflow-x: hidden;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
   .avoid {
     margin: 4px 0;
     page-break-inside: avoid !important;
   }
   .break_before {
     clear: both;
     display: block;
     page-break-before: always;
   }
   .break_after {
     clear: both;
     display: block;
     page-break-after: always;
   }
   .map_table,
   .main_table2 {
     margin-left: 15px;
     margin-right: 1px;
     margin-top: 15px;
     width: 640px;
   }
   .map_table {
     page-break-inside: avoid;
   }
   .title {
     color: #58595b;
     font-size: 11px;
     vertical-align: top;
   }
   .a_row .title {
     margin-right: 0;
     width: 100px !important;
   }
   .data {
     vertical-align: top;
     width: 255px !important;
     color: #262262;
     font-size: 11px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: left;
     text-transform: capitalize;
   }
   .a_row .data {
     width: 220px !important;
   }
   .main_table2 .bottom_border {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
   }
   .main_table2 .bottom_border {
     height: 0;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0 !important;
     width: 100%;
   }
   .main_table2 .a_cell,
   .main_table2 .a_title {
     padding: 5px;
   }
   .map_table img {
     padding: 10px;
   }
   .map_table .a_row {
     border: 3px solid #262262;
   }
   .a_table {
     display: block;
     overflow: hidden;
   }
   .a_row,
   .a_comp_row {
     display: block;
     overflow: hidden;
   }
   .a_cell,
   .a_title {
     display: inline-block;
     float: left;
     vertical-align: top;
   }
   .a_table,
   .a_title,
   .a_cell {
     border: 0 none;
   }
   .page_table2 {
     width: 670px !important;
   }
   .inner_table {
     margin-left: 15px;
     margin-right: 15px;
     width: 640px;
   }
   .a_title {
     font-weight: bolder;
     background-color: #262262;
     color: white;
     text-align: left !important;
   }
   .dont_split {
     page-break-inside: avoid !important;
   }
   .prior_transfer .a_row .title {
     width: 110px!important;
   }
   .prior_transfer .a_row .data {
     width: 210px!important;
   }
   p {
     margin: 0 !important;
     display: block;
     margin-block-end: 1em;
     margin-block-start: 1em;
   }
   @media print {
     .web_only {
       display: none;
     }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="page_table2 a_table">
    <div class="a_row">
      <div class="a_cell">
        <div class="a_table main_table2 inner_table dont_split prior_transfer">
          <div class="a_row">
            <div class="a_title" style="width: 100%;">
              <p>Prior Transfer</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="a_row">
            <div class="a_cell title">Recording Date:</div>
            <div class="a_cell data">2/11/2014</div>
            <div class="a_cell title">Doc #:</div>
            <div class="a_cell data">4242-424242</div>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom_border"></div>
          <div class="a_row">
            <div class="a_cell title">Transfer Amount:</div>
            <div class="a_cell data">$ 42,000</div>
            <div class="a_cell title">Doc Type:</div>
            <div class="a_cell data">-</div>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom_border"></div>
          <div class="a_row">
            <div class="a_cell title">Type of Sale:</div>
            <div class="a_cell data">Standard</div>
            <div class="a_cell title">Title Co:</div>
            <div class="a_cell data">Some Title Company</div>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom_border"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="a_row">
      <div class="a_cell">
        <div class="a_table map_table inner_table dont_split">
          <div class="a_row">
            <div class="a_title" style="width: 100%; height: 20px;">
              <p>Aerial Map</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="a_row">
            <div class="a_cell">

              <div id="googleMap" style="width:636px;height:380px;"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="a_row">
      <div class="a_cell">
        <div class="a_table main_table2 inner_table dont_split prior_transfer">
          <div class="a_row">
            <div class="a_title" style="width: 100%;">
              <p>Prior Transfer</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="a_row">
            <div class="a_cell title">Recording Date:</div>
            <div class="a_cell data">2/11/2014</div>
            <div class="a_cell title">Doc #:</div>
            <div class="a_cell data">4242-424242</div>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom_border"></div>
          <div class="a_row">
            <div class="a_cell title">Transfer Amount:</div>
            <div class="a_cell data">$ 42,000</div>
            <div class="a_cell title">Doc Type:</div>
            <div class="a_cell data">-</div>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom_border"></div>
          <div class="a_row">
            <div class="a_cell title">Type of Sale:</div>
            <div class="a_cell data">Standard</div>
            <div class="a_cell title">Title Co:</div>
            <div class="a_cell data">Some Title Company</div>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom_border"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try adding max-height for the div outside the map, not sure if that will help tho

Comment: Sadly, adding max-height to each of the local divs that include the map, including the map's div, didn't make any difference.  But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
#googleMap {
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that has finally worked is to embed the map in an iframe.

(among the sources with solutions: [This one](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1648) - but there were several others with the same advice).

For reference, since "put it in an iframe" required a lot more research on my part, here's what we ended up doing.  Rather than directly putting the full map script in the src for the iframe, we put it in a separate file (in our case, php since the map will be different at different times, but a plain html page if it's static would be fine) and then had that be the source.